# PHP Bookings System - Calculate Time Giving Wrong Result

Tags: php

Im working on a uni project for a simple car rental system. My problem comes in when calculating time (the amount of days and hours for the car rental)

Right now the time (where I am) is 12:15 PM

**CODE:**

```
        //Test Variables
         $ciDate = '2016-08-28';
         $ciTime = '13:10';

        //calc Time
        $calcDate = $ciDate.$ciTime;        
        $calcDate =  strtotime($calcDate);
        $remaining = $calcDate - time();
        $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
        $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
        $totPrice = $days_remaining * 4;
        //Disp Result
        echo $days_remaining. ' Days and ' . $hours_remaining. ' hours';
```

**MY PROBLEM**

When the above code gets executed, **I get back 2 Days and 5 hours**, which is incorrect considering *my time now is 12:15 PM 2016/08/26*

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess the problem is due to server time being different than my current time?

Any suggestions on how to fix the above problem, much appreciated.

EDIT:

At the time of writing the correct result should be 2 days and 1 hour

Comment: on which timezone  u r working?

Comment: Just check your `date('H:i', time())` and then set up your timezone.

Comment: consider using http://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/208809 instead of your current approach to avoid issues with DST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what timezone you are in but it appears your server is in a different zone.
You have MANY ways to fix this but here is the `code` way.

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier );
```

So if you are in Bagdhad you put

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Baghdad");
```

Or whereever you are.

See this link http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Comment: `Asia/Bangkok` =)

Comment: @vp_arth how you know that..?

Comment: When I set `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok")` I get back 2 days 0 hours...?

Comment: Try  `date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT+6");`